# ajax in Thymeleaf SpringMVC?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How to get fragment in main page using  AJAX in Thymeleaf SpringMVC?

I am having Spring MVC  and Thymeleaf templating engine. I'm a beginner in Thymeleaf.

I was wondering how can i use ajax to get part of website on how to do simple Ajax request to controller and in result rendering only a part of a template (fragment).

I was trying to return the fragment job.html into home.html

I don't want to use jquery I want to use plain vanilla javascript.

I think i need to use First clone the desired div Second empty the main div Third append the clone into the main div

Here is how  my controller look like

```
   @GetMapping("/generalization")
    public String selectSection(Model model) {
        List<DateasDto> section = generalizationService.getSection();
        model.addAttribute("section", section);
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/organisations/{id}/general")
    public String getGeneralSuccess(@PathVariable String id , Model model){
        List<AssessmentDto> gen = generalizationService.getGeneral(id);
        model.addAttribute("gen" , gen);
        return "Job";
    }
```

Here is how my html **home.html** look like

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/working.js}"></script>

<form onsubmit="getGen(event)" >

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="SelectSection">Select Section</label>
        <select  class="form-control" id="SelectSection" onchange="sectionChangeSelected()">
        <option value="">Select section</option>
        <option th:each="section: ${section}"
                th:text="${section.name}"
                th:value="${section.id}"
        ></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id = "table" ></div>

<div th:replace = "Job.html :: myTable " ></div>
</body>
```

here js look like

```
    const getGen= (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("get assessment called")
        let id= document.getElementById("SelectSection").value;
        console.log(id)
        let url = `/org/subjects/${id}/assessments`
        fetch(url) 
        .then(function() {
            
        })
        .catch(function() {
            
        });
    }
```

here is how my **Job.html** look like

```
<body>

<div th:fragment = "myTable" >
    <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td >Name</td>
                    <td >Date</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="gen : ${gen}">
                    <td th:text="${gen.Name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${gen.Date}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can render an HTML on the server side and return asynchronously on Ajax call: In your ajax call you can grab the returned HTML and append to a placeholder div.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/theUrl")
    public String aMethod() {
        return "theFileName :: fragmentName "; //THIS
    }
```

**Full example:**

The Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
class Ctrl {
    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String index() {
        return "mainPage";
    }
    @GetMapping(value = "/getMoreMessage")
    public String moreMessage(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("msg", "Server time is " + ZonedDateTime.now());
        return "frag/ajaxPart :: time-info ";
    }
}
```

The fragment in resources/templates/frag/ajaxPart.html:

```
<div th:fragment="time-info" class="tooltip">
    <H2>Received from server:</H2>
    <span th:text="${msg}"></span>
</div>
```

HTML page for '/main' mapping - `mainPage.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    const getData = () => {

        fetch('getMoreMessage').then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (html) {
            console.log(html)
            document.getElementById("myPlaceHolder").innerHTML += html;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        });
    }

</script>

<p><input type="button" onclick="getData( )" value="Get Data"/></p>
<div id="myPlaceHolder"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @gtiwari it helped me alot. I am asking in general is there way without using javascript  i can use fragments by using ```th:replace or th:insert``` and page should not refresh.

Comment: Thymeleaf performs rendering in server side. The only way you can pull the data from server and not refresh the page is using the Ajax call. The code in my answer is using Ajax operation. It doesn't refresh the page.